# vba excel choosing the right worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, range, worksheet, intersect

The Problem is in the section "Intersect" nearly at the end of the code. It continuous running only when the new sheet is brought into the foreground.
Moreover, is there a way to incooperate the command "Intersect" without the "with worksheet("spread")"?

```
Sub Schaltfläche2_Klicken() 

Dim wb As Workbook, wq As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet, datdatum

Set wb = Workbooks.Add
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Tabelle1")


ws.Select
ActiveWindow.Zoom = 80


ws.Name = "Spread"
datdatum = Now

Set wq = Workbooks.Open    
(Filename:="C:\Users\topal\Desktop\Spreaddeterminierung\Fundings 020718.xls")

wq.Sheets("Hypothekenbanken").Range("A11:P54").Copy
ws.Range("A3").PasteSpecial
wq.Sheets("Landesbanken").Range("A12:P38").Copy
ws.Range("A50").PasteSpecial

With Worksheets("Spread")
Intersect(.Range("4:92"), Range("F:F,H:H,J:J,M:M")).BorderAround , , 1
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed a `.` out from the second `Range` statement ...

```
Intersect(.Range("4:92"), Range("F:F,H:H,J:J,M:M")).BorderAround , , 1
```

Should be ...

```
Intersect(.Range("4:92"), .Range("F:F,H:H,J:J,M:M")).BorderAround , , 1
```

Assuming you are writing this sub in a module, `Range` without the `.` in front targets the active (foreground/frontmost) worksheet. On the other hand, if you are writing this sub in a worksheet, `Range` without the `.` in front targets the worksheet you are coding against. Thanks @Vityata for pointing this out!

---

In answer to your second question, you can do away with the `With` block by explicitly stating the worksheet in front of the `.Range` statments, eg ...

```
With Worksheets("Spread")
    Intersect(.Range("4:92"), Range("F:F,H:H,J:J,M:M")).BorderAround , , 1
End With
```

would become

```
Intersect(Worksheets("Spread").Range("4:92"), Worksheets("Spread").Range("F:F,H:H,J:J,M:M")).BorderAround , , 1
```

Comment: *Range without the . in front targets the active (foreground/frontmost) worksheet.* - not in this case. The OP is writing the code in the `Worksheet`, thus Range without the `.` takes the worksheet, in which the code stays and not the `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: I'll update my answer to reflect your insight, but the OP never says where the code is located so i assumed it was in a module, rather than a worksheet. Just out of interest, how can you tell, from the code, that it's not located in a module?

Comment: True. However, I guess that the `Schaltfläche2_Klicken` is most probably a `_Click` event from a workbook.

Comment: Now it is improving. I wish VBA did not translate the `_Click` events of Form elements to the local language. Sometimes it is a bit too much.

Comment: Hello, the code is in a modul. I have edited it and now the issue is the macro takes the sheet where the values are copied from in front. The other sheet where the values are copied in and with the sheet Name "spread" in behind. Thus, the "Intersect" command gets stuck.

Comment: Are you trying to get the intersection to work on the new sheet you add at the beginning of the code (ws), the 'spread' sheet, or over both sheets?